# Display returned PNG image string in HTML

Tags: php, html, image, encoding

I am facing an issue here, when I make a call to a proxmox API code that should return to me an image of some server graph(s), in that it just returns a `string` representing an actual PNG image. So, this is not base64 encoded string, or anything like that, so I am not sure how I should proceed with displaying this graph on my HTML page along with some other graphs ( that are also returned the same way from the API )

This is the data that I get back for an example, when making a call to the API for a particular graph.

[Image of the returned array for the API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfLw7.jpg)

Also, here is the actual code pasted.

````
array(2) { ["image"]=> string(16255) "PNG  IHDR ÈíMbKGDÿÿÿ ½§ IDATxípTÕÝÿOäghL  Ð4HBZÀÂ0F:åÖE£®ø£3D+R¥© 3   uFëc­~£F$%RIÖÝl`áGß?®Í¬ûãÞ³÷=û¹÷¾_¹³ï=ç}ÏÞû¾ç088È8ã]«`0ÀXÁ@0#â]ÑØØôJeeeà`DGeeeeeeYYZ)M°ºZZXBBîüùñ®@.^¼xäÈ¤¤¤³gÏ< ¢8Àº24ôáæÍ±¬ü`Ä¨Qñ®À7p»Ý]]]'O¾å[ÚÛÛ³³³ P`¨¯øâÆØ?ëëç<üp¼«ð úûûçÌ3vìXÆXEEEh¸<*ÇápDúÜ/¾xù¿þëßÏ1zô};wN2EníÔÉ$÷­[·:H¿íéé¹ûî»322/^ÜÛÛ­øÏ>«®XÀµB:hNrzÕÑÑQSS£R`Ã EEE.«°°°ºº:Zý½ôÒ/é½ë®_9òË#G~¤úY\>vÌÈÛñz½ÐQ>ËÑÏrtà³ø,G>Ç/þë_ÿ4É=ºßï¯ªªÚ¬*µ´´¬]»vüøñëÖ­knnV)éóù-ZôÊ+¯­tTÄP[S§NAGø,G>ËÑÏrtà³ø#Ün÷¾}ûo»í¶°Ü£`mÚ´iÚ´i+V¬P)Óßß¶lÙ²´´4Ï©ËåZ²dÉc=¶råÊÀ×¯öõ nß>1ÖÞlpö?ÿ#D§¸¸:ð9î:ð>[I>Ãç¸ë\mnjm½2eû´iÓRSS+**òòò D7É}Â  ×®]þoØ÷æåå}ôÑG§¬¬Ìårq83fÌðz½»ví>}zh§ÓY[[Ë_±HkiI.-5®ãv»srr  ø,G>ËÑÏrtà³ø¬Î¹sçô½Qs»Î»Un\½zõM7Ýôøã?÷Üs>oÛ¶maßÞÕÕuàÀ'xâ>4iRPêêê­[·ê¨'ºXï¾ûîÂc×®]{ÿý÷ï¸ãÀtGá¦M>þøã¼¼¼C=ýôÓÞv×]w­_¿~Å¡3®Î?o¼b±s--BtÜn7tTÏrtà³ø,G>ËÑÏ1bÂ   ÝÝÝW¯^½råJww÷Ä Äg,M` ÖèN°Î;wìØ±³gÏ2Æ&N8}úôqãÆ ú°g$XæÒÏrtà³ø,G>ËÑÏ1"99yÖ¬Y.\¸pá¬Y³öîÝT   lî+ÆÆF+¹ÇK.uww+)ãS#Ûc Btöïßøwø­¤ásÜuü~GG¾5K¿Ih$X°)6J°0Ë\:ðY|£åèÀg9:ð9^ ÁM`j#nj:ðY|£åèÀg9:ð9Fôõõµµµ½ÿþûï¿ÿ~[[[P$X°)º¬æææÔÔTÆØéÓ§=ZVVX    ÔFÜÔtà³ø,G>ËÑÏrtàs¼ 7ÀRiðûýLÄm§³³è(@>Ãg;èÀgù\âa½,¡¶¹U¶ËÏR>l#Ë48q¢©©©©©©³³³¨¨(¨ÑKN§³¶¶Ö¸".G>ËÑÏrtà³!>'t±^÷tíú\ÏÕ(@ÍR>3zíæOÌ&¹`aMºÓ<ñ¶E÷«¯¯ïøñãÊÛóóóSRR»D¨9XæÒÏrtà³ø,GGÏ½´ÚEMý9FtttL:µ¼¼¼¼¼<77÷ðáÃA`0+H°Ap¡N0r£åèÀg9:ðY,9:èÏ1Â¬Ü`Ð    0Vr×    Fîrtà³ø,G>ËÑA%Gý9F4TÜë`Q>Ãg+éÀgëù¬ÂÌå}6u°cß$è·D/b,séÀg9:ðY|£#p¬Oæ¨Õó!5HùÌèµK?z/666ª!:ÀÂ,`0HìXä.*`¹tà³ø,G>ËÑÁ,9:èÏ1B}tÅ`0/H°Ap¡N0r£åèÀg9:ðY,9:èÏñ    ³ÄF ²LrÏ¤ñÛ854ÑÙ¿?tàsÜuà3|¶(ïti×gjþPóZ»è\¦A$XÌ ,`}  V[[[vvvFFFBBB¤2ä,ÌÁ2|£åèÀg9:%Gý9L>ýôéÓ{öì9qâ²4z(ñI°úç"Á     ,`#s°ü~ww÷_|ñ­o}ë[n0aBào£K°fÏ¾`Á-ÓÓÓs÷Ýwgdd,^¼¸··W_¥`K>ËÑÏrtà³$XrtÐcÇ¨Q£¾ýíoÿð?LKK;zôhÐo£K°î»ï¾'|ò[nyï½÷Ö¯_ìØ±Ð2UUUiiiO<ñÄæÍÏ9ö7H°  0»_~ùåüüük×® ;6lµk×?~ÝºuÍÍÍ*j>oÑ¢E¯¼òJè¯`K>ËÑÏrtà³$XrtÐãEÔÜÇ¤INg}}}ØýýýiiiË-KKKóù|t\.×%K{ì±+W¾~µ¯opûö1/+}Âà6¹´TNNNtàsÜuà3|¶¶·I×¨ÏÒvSúCÊgí¢3ðöÛC­­YÐ3ÉýÂ ¿ûÝïþñþ6//ï£>ÊÈÈðxËÑÏrtà³!>'t±^÷'sÔêÃy?¤|fôÚ%Ì]"nõÐC=õÔS&MzçwNgggghÕ«WßtÓM?þøsÏ=çóù¶mÛZÆáptuu8pà'øà&MTs°h9XÀ Tæ`UTT,Z´hÊ)[·n¾Dèp8ËlÚ´éã?ÎËË;tèÐÓO?I*--í®»îZ¿~ý+.^¼ô[ÌÁ2|£åèÀg9:¢|Æ,uÐãVr`V`J°+++_ÁJî\PqSÓÏrtà³ø,G   ôçxâCµi7íÍ}mÌ ,`Ý   VcÈ½Ô¬K.uww+¶v{J6ÃSÄeéÀgøl%i>·}¾¨oiùCÍç;]ÚõQ4?Ô|¦Ö.!:~¿¿££CrDKå7    -âÒãÀC`ÌÁÒ  ®=ËÑÏrtà³j>[uæ`ÉÑ¡Ö©é"4ÄBñéqà!0î«¯¯ïøñãÊÛóóóSRR ÁâÚ|£åèPóÙª ,9:Ôú35ÝtttL:µ¼¼¼¼¼<77÷ðáÃA`@|@úb;{»P ;Ájnn.((HMMe>}úèÑ£eee`qAmÄMM>ËÑÏrt¨ùlÕ    AÑc,µµÅxe ý5EEE'Nhjjjjjêìì,** *âÓQØÙC;·] TE(¬eFø­¤#ÓgõxÖy²³Ïv^§]?û;·FÖÁj!¨,H cgíÜvYÉ½²²rxù+¬¥e´HÀg9:ðY5­:Çs°äè,mo¢C­]¢ttôÕW_%$$|õÕWçÎ9rdP$X@ÇÎÚ¹íÑ`;vìË/¿üÎw¾ÓÕÕuåÊiÓ¦M2%°,.¨¸©éÀg9:ðY5­Ð Á£+FÜzë­YYY¥¥¥A£+¹¶ãØÙC;·] ç`Eú/CÅ    µ75ø,G>KÐiâ:ãç!ÁR   $X±CåBFp¥,Óà÷ûÛ8OggÑQ|£Ný`TvB+ls«l4_»{©v}vsöõ\Öà´e|·ÇóÔGéú3{Ü°ªÏ<íúìfy>NÇÈ2 ±ÊBKô¡Óé¬­­5®s®¥%¹´Ô¸ÛíÎÉÉN$à³.¶´½åo3K5Kj^ Ö®^÷tm9íR|~ky©z!õá¼ÄSÐëþdý%PGÈqÇQûi:ýG³?ªIub·Ð(Ñæ`Uç[PkÌúPk»±³vn»@l´»æ`K>ËÑ±ê\ jsh¨ùLÍjÇ «úcÕþLM'v ÁÀXõlZ»`;{hç¶ N¬Ô)ñ°.íÇßjSëXõLZAÍgjþ Á2µþLM'v Áj(g?<à)ÖXõlZ»`;{hç¶ÄF  ²LrÏ¤ñÛ8E=­ÔÓ¿%ëôF¼Y}øu<­]Ï<·mSk×.®~hIytxü1cu|¦Ö$ôgjí¦cpu`5pD«îjíBe.ìì¡Û.Ý  V__ßñãÇ·'''ççç§¤¤ `)`¹tp_K<_/Ý©þSâÑÕ.jsh¨õgjþÒÁ,9:Ôú35ÝtttL:µ¼¼¼¼¼<77÷ðáÃA`5pDQûÚ¼:j}   ¹°³¿ïB­iRt'XÍÍÍ©©©±Ó§O=z´¬¬,°@|,Ã¡^ ¹tp$GGÏÊ¼:N¬ÐPëÏÔüAe"y£É=[nN8ÑÔÔÔÔÔÔÙÙYTTT ºëµ×^Û¼ysOOÏôéÓ7oÞ[ÕíÀÛoµ¶^qRYY©l3=þyqqñºuëÂþväÈýýýwÜqGÿÈ#Ãaµ··544-ðà^Á`s³®®.{ê°Îë¬SCu^_úÍrêcg9÷WÁ>ûýº¸vQ«yê#jqBª?_t|¦Ödêp¶KÓg«úÃQÂ_þòámà?íxíÐ¡C?ùÉO~üãGºüâóùÞxã Ç£Ì®ËOúS¯×vclÜ¸qÑV,,É¥¥êJ<\ûæÎÙ+¢>999"dÈéümf©jí¢¦#Êç#é´Ú%¤>%Öz=iÝ3Ås·µþLmÒÑ<>sbU¨ùL­]¢tbGÔ}ôÑúúú7&&ïüùókjjkjjJ#ï×;w¾øâ+V¬8uêTèo¥ÍÁâ]1ÆÎüÖ5cj:Ôæ¬XUs°ThâÒáùÊSëÏÔöµ¹AVõÏõá|víò´üÑÍðõÁH¢»0hy¯×;nÜ¸ [=raqqq]]]FFFXå-;vìØ¾}û;ï¼3fÌÀÒî"´ó(<À:à.BsáÚ¾0#vöÚ]ÔÖØãDÔ]A­è¬ ëÊ¼ !ZffæîÝ»½^ïîÝ»Ã®ßrÏ=÷477®½»q¤µ3~«ê Á£C­?SÛ_Ô«úCÍgÎúh®±WÐKëIºQ¿a%w;ýðè`ÆjíBe.ìì!ÍK]sÞ³úpB%Á,séP;ã·ª,9:Ôú3µýE-Y±ª?Ô|R½¬+Ö$b¹Ö¥Kº»»ý~?û}F¶§³³5Ë(_Nõ2 ÆëcF>»YÛgjí2£Ï¢ú3µïÌvÙÙg:<ÇgjýÏ<íùwæÖï÷wttx½^fÐÙîD/:ÎÚÚZã:Êk*8ãå^÷'sÜêv»ÜY*MÓ¥í-o-/P;ëðø,ª?s^2Õ.!õ¨#Äg&îûeÕãæñjýY¦g»üXi:è¾DtM0ô!Ñæ`þÐÁsx Ö.ÌÁ2vöÐs°dêpbdô æ`é×øÕ¡6gÅª:%GZ¦¶¿Déàø,GÔ,:F¨ ô·H°³ëÙðfLhx Ö.$XæÂÎRK¨ép"ê.ÂP`q3$u¨ñ[U   jýÚþ¢¬XÕj>SkK$XÙõìøC3&4<Çg3¶K Îõ\ÖàVÙþ¯_ÏÔú³´ýedM^"t:µµµÆuêÏ½¨v ©¿&B|fâ¾_B?Ôö;ã8>ó@°]¢?¢þîù;Èõg:ÄîQ9DXE«úÃùQjçñ ³Î¢V37ã¼(jû]flçñGÚªúÔæNhVÐ+¥K^ã¨CmÎ §Îõ\µ&q¿xXBÆÃ,Ã:{35vºòóÿ·©éüáDT»4Ïßjírü¾ügÌÁÊJîeee,dh¥1³ýÈÄªþPk¨3Z$Xtê,JÇ% ßXµ>Ôt81rPYÌýÌ3³fÍjoo¯¨¨ü-,.Lz$MÇ¤   &÷»´dZ¦ÐP;ã§æ´KAZÒCíø#ÙgM¨µ+î   ÛíÞ·o_rròm·ÝÖÞÞT    cf;«Uý¡Ö.j)µ¶±Î¢tÌøY¢0i"¢UëCMÝ  ÖÁo½õÖ±cÇF*@.ÁRiPî4~«¨§y=³îÓÚöwmÍØ.û§>ý9¡¶EÜr¶KÚÓìÖGÔþuÜ Ö©íwj>S;þØÙgiþY¦¡¸¸XetÅ`ñ¬wKÑjíõYÔîã   ¬H4ÑÄªõ¡¦ÃIìi `)`AÎg,ù·ú`:¢ê£Ù9ï£6gÚ#jsV¨ù#­?sÂYÍ¤åI}6Nì@ÅÙÎêx°êI¢ Ö.jRk»U÷,u$'»B>«úLM«%XC½,9:V}v5p&ªµÏÔü1]æIv=Lç³IubGt ÖðÀHå]===UUU9sf]]]zzzXõÏEe$XêPk5©µÝªû   :fÜ§Ô>jÉM¬ÁÁAÍÙ \.Waaauuµ¾j!Á£KjûÝªg¢Ôj>SóÇªý?VõNìÐ3K=ÊËËÛ³gOff¦Çã)++s¹\|>ßªU«V®\¹råÊ H°Kjí¢æ!µ¶[uñ·KKÞlÆ}Jí³x <Ù4Áâ¡¿¿?--mÙ²eiii>/R1ËµdÉÇ{,htuµ¯opûö==Ê ÛàVùQ)£D/e zÝ?z½%¡©lK<Úõq»ÝBÚ¥©Ãß.!:KÛ5|Õ.jþÈ¬O\!ûK`?µ¿4}åÎúÃ-½n¥¤Ê¶uHÏ¢ö»LEõCÎ-©ïµþLÍ·ßjm½òØf!Ä$Áúè£222Ô¬3fx½Þ]»vM>=´©ÿM4Ï2©­_eÆ³^¨µÔÚnÕý%V:ò`Æ}Jí³x Ù`aþüù555555¥¥¥íÜ¹óÅ_\±bÅ©S§BKjÖÞLÖàV¿eÞh.)Íu§$¯_9XêP!¤?3ëúlÕ9X:Çÿ>Ck¿SóÚ÷Ýª>SÓ:ï"TPÞhy<å.Ââââººº°:Ê[vìØ±}ûöwÞygÌ1H%X2?Ëªe¨A­]Ô<¤Öv«î/;ïwÌ¸O©}Ôú³M¬Áo2üb`ÌÌÌÝ»w{½ÞÝ»w]¾å{îinn]1b £wDMgi{Kè²ÈA?%mjg6þx4Z thjýÙªß«úLMÏH°Ô¡Ö.«%XÒ@e¢2ÔVIæA¬?<ÐI_x°ê÷B2ïì¨vZ?4ãgñ@-y²i% !    Vçë[üT~8¡vDJgo&<Ù¢>Gjg6þh¶É:¤ú3ãðYÔKN¨ÍåÕ.jý    :ÔÚE?Á"7ÀºtéRww·ßïgÿ±O÷¶u}vs6ûÏ×&ÒVø©®¦`°>HB+lsGÚ×Êx}dêÎÎVNIù#Ógjþ±>>ßø¢²%Ø.Míâ35êêÏëCMGsë÷û;::¼^/D/:ÎÚÚZ"  ]li{Ë[ËK×Çívçää)ñ°3ÿvI×Ðá¹¬PÐ«­Ã8.©ôº?£¦ÃÕkiI|Ç(¿yt8/9  ñG¦Ïpú£ O?äìÏr|æDÏ÷»´ï2}éÀv 9þðèp"Ígj:Äî!Ñ9XÔ®sÚZYËü¾ó,ÍsãAZÅ´~8o4×ß÷3ÿv³LõfM°¨ÝíbF¨%X¢îÈU3&Ô|§*©ï»U÷»UQwCñoµKòg!Á ÏYj¼>ÔÎ ©%4Ïøyæ¬h¤PýPÝþDëÏB¾_¦Û_êÏ<ßwþDVÎ\.NHù,PGHâSè&X¿ý¹ö,sùQCf* yÝ)RëY5ÉàÁÎm7cêÆµïLd¦ì21ãz¿_6ZKY¦A¹gÒøò Ç4Ëðl÷ïßo=½¬íÔ~õ[²¯ç²ÿõñç¶Û;]í7Z£W([Çamxê#ji¶³>fìÏBö»äv   ñYà÷ÔqCÙ_êËÍ?½@E§ÄÃVïh²l48?vÒÚ_Çgõ}Ñ:ôõ÷ÔøßeR¿ì¸L´Ü¨Í¯"¸ê73ÛY/Ôö0ç*Y«¦­Ø(ÁR°ê³­ª#jåkåìÇ8ÊÙüÏz5ibÕþLmm«ú,Dg¯7 CIDATx1RãOnXÚ®ñë¹\ÑIùCPG³?ïÍÔØÊ?±  °6?#,{bçÔ$X:Á¨R>óaôÌÏü:i",ép&Öë·¯3¡?uÐã,@¬@ ,`ä.G>ËÑ1Ï&Ûa:MªåèÀçxAn¥,Óà÷ûÛSy"Î³U|ÏvÐÏðÙJ:ðYekÇeNgmm­q«®`KM>ËÑÏrtà³ø,G>«»KDXX9X:Áµg9:ðY|£åèÀg9:ð9^ ÁMA¥ÜåèÀg9:ðY|£åèÀçx6 N0r£åèÀg9:ðY|£ã¹ÖÁ2£|ÏVÒÏðÙJ:ðYeu°ôõ?äèÀg9:ðY|£åèÀgu°`0K'¸ö,G>ËÑÏrtà³ø,G>Çè¬ªªªÎ9³®®.==]_M` Ö(  Ö[?¼à©§&L"P9ºkÃ EEE.«°°°ººZwM`K>ËÑÏrtà³ø,G>óÐµgÏËKì«©¹â÷Ò.ÁÊËËÛ³gOff¦Çã)++s¹\úÊh"/Á*)a­­ÚÅæÍc{÷Æ¾6ô?öÄÎûÝÎm7#Ø_ÀJµµ @ùï)S<ùd®ÛFDUº¿¿?--mÙ²eþó}>î2aq¹\¯¾úêu¿ÿÊç·÷öþ2+ëóç/gd{í/_Ö(¢©sv``¢ú8qâÙ³&ÓáðçÇh[$êpõgûÝªßk¹¹Ú>=zY«íÔÚEMGX1C»>6Þ_RÄtF$'ûo»-é¦®z½a·W¾ø"aÄvåÊ·¢ñÝ+%%Åçó½ñÆ'55Uw°äççoÜ¸Qù·ÓéÜøÂQÕ-,C­­£çÍ3®ÓÝÝ}óÍ7C'ðY|£åèÀg9:ð­#Fuÿý³W¯1jÍèæ`Í?¿¦¦fpp°¦¦¦4BÆSF1cÆè{c¢£oª¾}tà³ø,G>ËÑÏrtà3¹óçß·sçÜÿ\ÔèE;Ëãñ(w×ÕÕedd0ÆG HØ2ÑR]]=fáj__Ò7×êÀg9Àg9Àg9Àg9ÀçxAt¡QËïZèèB££«»ï¾;##cñâÅ½½½1GÙÙÙaßX&$ÔÆÆÆâââÔÔÔâââwß}ó]ðY}>uæ°: }>¿öÚkßýîw'MTZZÚÖÖV¢ÏçÙ³g§§§/X°àÀau@ ú|VØºu+þÆ¢,MBWÛü<ðÀý÷ßéÃÅ"é@Býyè¡¶lÙòå_nÞ¼yÍ5ïÏêèó9°'GÒèóy÷îÝ¯¾úêÉ'×¬Y³jÕª°: }>¿ùæ;vì8yòä/~ñ{ï½7¬DÏ± èî"¤CKKË={Æ¿nÝº²²²á×^ýuåìÌceee]»v­¤¤ä^¾>«£Ïg>wìØ¡ücîÜ¹}}}/_Ïêèóùå_f]¼xqhhhìØ±au@ ú|öûýUUU7o^½zu$ ³&XÃ«m¥¥¥®¶õ§?ýé;îYô×hppðäÉÊÉÉyðÁUtB¨?/¾øâ½÷Þ{ã7Þwß}¿ÿýïbA>¾>«£ÏgûúúV­ZµfÍn¸>«£ÛgÃ1iÒ$§ÓY__V¢ÏçM6M6mÅ*:@f` ¯¶uúôéáÕ¶®\¹²mÛ¶~Xý½©©©O>ùd{{{$0L¨?UUUõõõ>¯®®îà||VGÏ<: Ý>:thþüùóçÏægÂê@tû<88ØÛÛ»eËå>«£Ïç?üáo¾ù¦2KÙÂçaÖVØÕ¶vîÜ9eÊïÿûêï=wî\MMÍ÷¾÷½H:`PúúúcJé\'ô]ðY}>óè@ôù¼cÇG}´¾¾~ãÆau@ ú|~è¡º»»F¥Ïêèóy```xú¦²Ï1è2 ]m«¬¬ìGYºtép± kÏÊh=99yîÜ¹¿ýío³³³¬ÚeaBýyûí·7lØpòäÉ¬¬¬_ÿú×-bk¡Águôùxÿ clpp>«#Äg¯×;00UÐçó_ÿú×§~Úëõæçç?óÌ3¥¥¥èÏêèóyá×ás0ë,f½D@°`0ÀXÁ@0`,ÁªtÐÆÄnÁÒH«ÐÀÔÄe\!èX1Öy=ÌSW%Ò@Êì áFLÀ¨Âp@cðí¸D Ø°Ç¶mÛ²²²òòòvíÚ¥¼xêÔ©åËgddÌ=ûÿü§RL  ÿ1üö W"iÀòW¸Ýî¦§§/\¸Ðívkê«¼=*b`={öÓO?Ý²eË¯~õ+åõë×/[¶ìóÏ?öÙg×®]ËTR¸á(ýWEvÀÈ¸ÂétVTTtvv9ÎHéíQÕ;G¤9XauGooïØ±c¯^½zã7={1uæÌ¥@bbâÀÀÀpáH"¯Õép8æ`Åb\1yòäO?ýÔáp|õÕW·Þzë_~T,Ò¿uý$÷(;v,c,))éêÕ«Ê+;5`+©¤¤¤.«e\&¹WWW0?~ü±cÇä×æ\qûí·ÿñ<þüK/½tûí·+/feeíÜ¹óÂ555êo8°~óßø|¾ÂÂÂ ¹c<òÈB'¹3c³Ì`aøÇÏ?ÿü{ï½ÛÔÔôüóÏ+/>óÌ3ë×¯6mÚÄeCßÑÏÁV«@TXx\ÝhF`0ÀXÁ@0`,Á` ÿ¸°.ü<¾ôIEND®B`" ["filename"]=> string(50) "/var/lib/rrdcached/db/pve2-vm/102_netin_netout.png" }
````

I've tried saving this string to a file with .png extension and then trying to open it in an image viewer, however, my guess it that it always gets corrupted due to file encoding issues.

Comment: `echo "<img src="data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($yourarray['image']) . '">';`

Answer (score 3):

Either via

```
<img src="script.php?id=something" />
```

where script.php will make the request you've used to get the array and then serve

```
header('Content-type: image/png')
echo $result['image'];
```

or by [embedding the png data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) within the image tag like

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($result['image']); ?>" />
```

for the second approach the amount of image data should be feasibly small. And then the image won't be cached separately from the html document. But that might be ok, depending on the use case.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) However, this is returning a broken image for me, could be that the image string I get returned from the API call is not valid PNG ?
How could I test if manualy providing `base64_encode()` function with a PNG string ( from a local PNG image after I opet it's contents in notepad for example ), would return a proper image? Since, when I try to paste that contents directly as base64_encode param, it gets broken, due to a lot of weird characters in it.